# Black screen while installing on a HP Pavillion 15

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, system-installation

I'm asking for help installing Ubuntu 64bits on a HP Pavillion 15 through USB.

- Disabled Fast-boot
- Disabled Secure Boot
- Prioritized USB boot

So I boot into GRUB I select either run or install and I get a black screen. If I select `Try Ubuntu` I have the Ubuntu loading screen then I get a black screen.

I've tried to Enable Legacy support and prioritize USB (something about if legacy is enabled UEFI is still prioritized) and I still have no luck.

Comment: @vivid_vibe not even close...

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting bios to defaults?
More info is needed - 
How did you create your usb boot media?
Did you verify that the boot image is correct?
What type/size is the usb media?

Also try this:
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/testing-your-system-for-usb-boot-compatibility/